# Can you run jar files in Pentaho spoon tool?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I want to run a jar file that has java code, inside the Pentaho spoon tool. This run is a single step by accepting an input, running the java class on top of this data and then providing the output somewhere. Is this possible with Pentaho Spoon?

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy. Just pop the jar file into the lib directory with the other jars, and call it from the modified javascript step.  ( Or maybe even the java class step if thats more suitable for what you're trying to do )

I've done this several times - most recently for some custom decoding which had to be done in java, and couldnt be done in the java step because janino didnt support it.

Comment: Hi codek , i am trying to execute a jar file from pentaho ETL .can you please look in to the following issue [link]http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?155536-How-to-execute-jar-file-from-pentaho-ETL Thanks in advance Code

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

- leave the jar in your project directly, no copying necessary
- create a simple bash script "run.sh" in your project folder with
  "java -jar yourjar.jar" in it. you can also add that line directly
  within spoon and skip this step
- to your job, add a "execute shell script" and point to run.sh

done, the result code of the script determines success or not

why this way? I hate the way the api is documented, no code completion in spoon, Java or Javascript, this way you can write your code outside and rely on working systems